# Poisson probability

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Given that $N(t)$ follows a Poisson process with rate $\lambda t$, How can I compute the following probability $P(2N(7) - N(1)=3)$?

It seems that I can't use the property that the sum of independent Poisson variables is Poisson with the sum of the rates, because $N(7)$ and $N(1)$ don't seem independent. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

- $N(1)$ and $N(7)-N(1)$ are independent and $N(7)-N(1)$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $6\lambda$.
- $2N(7)-N(1)=2[N(7)-N(1)]+N(1)$

Comment: Thank you for your help :)! Am I right that $2[N(7)-N(1)] \sim \mathrm{Poi}(12 \lambda)$ and hence the whole thing is $\mathrm{Poi}(13 \lambda)$?

Comment: No. If $N$ is Poisson then it takes values in $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ so that $2N$ only takes values takes values in $\{0,2,4\dots\}$. This shows that $2N$ is not Poisson.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. I don't have a clue in that case what distribution it follows, I've never encountered that before. Can you please tell me?

Comment: If you know the distribution of $N$ (here in fact $N(7)-N(1)$) then you also know the distribution of $2N$. Btw, if $2N$ only takes values in $\{0,2,4\dots\}$ and $M$ (here in fact $N(1)$) only takes values in $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ then $2N+M=3\iff [N=0$ and $M=3]$ or $[N=1$ and $M=1]$.

Comment: $N(7)-N(1) \sim N(6)$ right? But I don't quite see how I should know the distribution of $2N$ then?

Comment: $N(7)-N(1)$ and $N(6)$ are not the same, but yes... they have the same distribution. $P(2N=2k)=P(N=k)$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$  gives you the distribution of $2N$. The RHS is known to you, because you know the distribution of $N$. Cheers, I am leaving now.